# Induction stove in hand-luggage?

Tags: air-travel, europe, hand-luggage, airbaltic

I am wondering whether you are allowed to take the following induction stove in hand-luggage while flying from Vilna (Lithuania) to Stockholm (Sweden) with AirBaltic.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you haven't stuffed the insides of the device with illicit materials and as long as it meets the size/shape/weight requirements for hand carried luggage, there's no reason you can't bring it on board. It might look funny on the x-ray machine and they may swab it for explosives/drugs, but if that check is negative then I don't see why you can't bring it on board.

Both countries are part of the EU so there shouldn't be any customs duty.

Now, whether it's "legal" for you to plug it into the electrical system in Sweden is another issue. I assume that it has the proper CE stamp on it (and not the fake China Export sticker).

Comment: So it is allowed to carry it on board. Good! :) Otherwise, I have to throw it away if I cannot carry it on hand-luggage. - - Yes, it fits the size criteria.